# Snowflake where clause not functioning properly fetching the incorrect answer

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

One of the query

```
select * 
from "ANALYTICS_DEV"."DBT_schema"."WF3_M3_REGRESSION_MODEL"
where "quantile"= 0.8
```

is fetching no records but there are records that would satisfy the condition.
The where clause is not working fine in snowflake. WF3_M3_REGRESSION_MODEL is a model in dbt that make use of the python in snowpark to do a regression model.

I tried using multiple equality operators in snowflake and its not helping.

Comment: what is the data type of quantile ? if its float/decimal with larger precision, you can use `quantile>=0.8 and quantile<0.9`. Actual data isnt stored like .8 but may be .8123456 and thats making your sql fail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please update your question with the ddl for the table and sample data that you think your query should return